# Curl Command throwing' invalid grant error' on Windows command line

Tags: docusignapi

I have generated the JWT Token for DocuSign through the https://jwt.io .The signature is verified.
Now to obtain the Access token I am using following Command in Curl,on Windows Command line tool.Rrefering the Document https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken.I am getting "invalid Grant".What is the problem with my request?I know my token is correct because the token verifies the signature.

```
curl --data "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=YOUR_JSON_WEB_TOKEN" --request POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token
```

Comment: Did you obtain consent from the user via URL so that Integratorkey can impersonate that user for whom you are generating the accesstoken?

Answer (score 1):

`invalid_grant` is the the publicly facing version of several errors rolled together. If you've hit your limit of troubleshooting, I'd recommend opening a case with [DocuSign Support](https://support.docusign.com/), and provide your Demo Account ID, UserID, Integrator Key and the value of an x-DocuSign-TraceToken of a failing assertion. The plaintext version of your assertion would be helpful as well.

Here's a few things to check:

`aud` value - must be *exactly* `account-d.docusign.com` (for demo) or `account.docusign.com` for prod. Including https:// or any other value will fail.

`sub` value - must be an active userID (in GUID format) in the appropriate environment.

`iss` value - must be a valid client ID

Private Key used for signing - must be associated with the Client ID in the correct environment. If you're using a key generated in Production but the assertion is directed to `account-d.docusign.com` it will fail. In some cases it can take a few minutes for a newly generated keypair to be valid in the Account Server, so if you've just generated that key, wait a bit and try again.

Timestamps used - Your `exp` value must not have passed, and if you are using an `nbf` value, it must be in the past. Confirm your computer's clock is correctly configured - if it's dramatically off, your application could be generating invalid assertions because of that.

Comment: My aud is correct,sub and iss are valid.Actually I am just testing everything on my local machine with my organisation's Sandbox Docusign account. I have  obtained the authorization code,I have obtained  consent from my user account.I did this following by using follwing URL in browser.- https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?
response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=7c2b8d7e-83c3-4940-af5e-cda8a50dd73f&redirect_uri=https://client.example.com.Now I am into 3rd step ,after generating JWT token.I have isntalled curl on my Local windows machine and executing curl commnd

Answer (score 0):

The pro-tip is to use a library to generate the JWT and convert it to an Access Token.

See the JWT examples for code examples in many languages. The examples use either a JWT method from a DocuSign SDK or a lower level JWT library.

- C# .NET Core https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-csharp-jwt-core
- C# .NET Framework https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-csharp-jwt-framework
- PHP https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-php-jwt
- Java  https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-java-jwt
- Node.js https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-node-jwt
- Python. https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-python-jwt
- Ruby https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-ruby-jwt

See the repositories’ Readme files for installation and configuration instructions.

Comment: For Now I am not using any programming language,but just trying to generate Access Token Locally.I have installed Curl on my local windows machine.So Am  following correct ,steps?Can I do this on my local machine?

Comment: As you've discovered, it is not easy to do. But it is doable. The hardest part is that you will need to calculate a digital signature for the JWT using the private key you have downloaded from DocuSign. See the JWT standards for more info.

Comment: See the PHP example for an example of setting the individual JWT attributes.

Comment: Thank You, Larry.I am trying it with informatica now.For Moving an envelope api,just X-Docusign -Authentication would be enough ?Because with this header that contains user name ,password and integrator key,its throwing me Invalid Token Format."Token did not match the security token schema" error.I am using a put request /accounts/{accountId}/folders/{folderId}} with envelope id and 'from folder id in request body

Comment: DocuSign legacy authentication header authentication works fine if implemented correctly.  Please ask a new question if you want to discuss a different issue.